# Se puede conservar la fecha seleccionada de un elemento imput type date despues de enviado el dato con el boton submit?

Tags: html, html5, asp.net-mvc

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en asp.net mvc y en la parte de la vista tengo un campo , este campo fecha lo uso para enviar un dato al controlador y recibir un resultado, pero cuando envío el valor mediante el input type="submit se borra la fecha que el usuario selecciono y me gustaría que la fecha se quedara seleccionada para que si el usuario quiere hacer otra consulta pueda hacerla sin tener que volver a seleccionar la fecha.

he buscado en varias paginas de internet y dice que no es posible, pero si hay alguna forma me gustaria saberla